# Linux kernel Hardware breakpoint registration failed with EACCES

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, hardware, breakpoints, drivers

I am using below code in my driver, but the `register_wide_hw_breakpoint` returns an `EACESS` error.

```
      hw_breakpoint_init(&attr);
        attr.bp_addr = kallsyms_lookup_name(ksym_name);
        attr.bp_len = HW_BREAKPOINT_LEN_4;
        attr.bp_type = HW_BREAKPOINT_W | HW_BREAKPOINT_R;

        sample_hbp = register_wide_hw_breakpoint(&attr, sample_hbp_handler, NULL);
                if (IS_ERR((void __force *)sample_hbp)) {
                        ret = PTR_ERR((void __force *)sample_hbp);
                        printk(KERN_INFO "Breakpoint registration failed:%d\n",ret);
                }
```

What could be possible reasons for this? Am I missing a `CONFIG` option which will grant access to hardware registers?

Additional info: My platform is X86_64, Linux

Please help.

Comment: Please specify the Linux distro and kernel version you are using.

Comment: By the way, did you check that kallsyms_lookup_name() found the needed symbol successfully?

Comment: One more question: is the task that calls into your driver running with root privileges (or, to be exact, does it have CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability)? If it does not, it could be the reason for -EACCES.

Comment: @Eugene **kallsyms_lookup_name()** return is ok.

Comment: @Eugene, i added debug logs , i found that **perf_event_alloc** callback is getting failed. CAP_SYS_ADMIN  check is in **find_get_context** callback which is called after perf_event_alloc. _Additional Info: register_wide_hw_breakpoint calls **perf_event_create_kernel_counter** which further calls perf_event_alloc and then find_get_context_.